# how to keep on update a system current time in a column TIMESTAMP

Tags: oracle, timestamp

I have created a column with data type timestamp. I want to update particular column .I tried but its not updating.

```
 Create table mytime
 (name varchar(20),schdul timestamp(6)); 

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER mytable_entry_stamp 
        BEFORE UPDATE OF schdul ON mytime
        FOR EACH ROW 
       DECLARE 
          t1 timestamp:= current_timestamp ;
BEGIN 

      :new.schdul:= case :new.schdul
                        when 'shree' then t1
                        else :new.schdul
                    end; 
END;
```

Comment: A trigger does not fire on a schedule.  Why are you trying to do this?  What problem are you trying to solve?  There may be other options.

Comment: there is a colum schdul i need update that column with new current time . that is the task .

Comment: may I know what are the other methods ?

Comment: You are trying to set a Timestamp into a varchar column? Please, do the right modeling to your database. This is far way uggly. `:new.schdul:= case :new.schdul when 'shree' then t1 else :new.schdul end;`

Comment: @JorgeCampos - in the CREATE TABLE statement `schdul` is set up as a `TIMESTAMP(6)` column.

Comment: I saw it. I find it odd this portion of the code: ` case :new.schdul when 'shree'` How could a timestamp be 'shree' ?

Comment: @JorgeCampos - see my answer below.

Comment: Yeah, I saw it. Looks like he mixed up the columns. :)

Comment: schedule a job with DBMS_SCHEDULER package.  Read the docs on it.

Answer (score 0):

In your trigger code it looks like you meant

```
:new.schdul:= case :new.name  -- <<=== changed to name
                when 'shree' then t1
                else :new.schdul
              end;
```

The entire trigger could be simplified a bit to

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER mytable_entry_stamp 
  BEFORE UPDATE OF schdul ON mytime
  FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
  :new.schdul:= case :new.name
                  when 'shree' then CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
                  else :new.schdul
                end; 
END MYTABLE_ENTRY_STAMP;
```

This gets rid of the extra temp variable, which is unnecessary.

Best of luck.

Comment: its changing when i update schdul column .I want when system time changes that time my column should update. example if my system is showing 11:00 am then my column should show 11:00am but when my system shows 11:03 am without updating manually my schdul should update.

Comment: The time changes always, do you want to update the table every millisecond? If you want the current time simply select  `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`, i.e. `select case name when 'shree' then CURRENT_TIMESTAMP else schdul end`

Comment: As others have said, triggers only fire when you make a change to the database. To accomplish what you're trying to do you'd need to have a job running in the background which would update the database every minute. This is not what triggers do. [Here's a link to the the Oracle Database Administrator's Guide section on the Job Scheduler](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/scheduse.htm). I haven't used this so I really can't give you much advice on how to go about it, but read through the docs, try your best, and then ask about whatever issues come up. Best of luck.

Comment: Thank you  Bob Jarvis for your suggestion .I know how to schedule jobs in scheduler but when i will try to schedule a job it is giving error insufficient privileges. so I am trying with trigger.

Comment: The trigger isn't going to suddenly start firing whenever the time changes. Triggers don't work that way, and there really isn't a way to make them suddenly start doing what you want. If you don't have privileges to create a job you'll need to talk to your DBA or other site personnel (managers, etc) to get set up with the needed privileges. Best of luck.

Comment: Thank you bob for your feedback.